# Software not running properly in 22.04

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, musescore

I now have 22.04.  Since installing it, Firefox only properly loads if I click on a link in Thunderbird; my music writing software (Musescore, using an appimage) won't load, and I think there must be something else, too.  What I get is a solid black screen.  Ubuntu upgrades have never done this for me before.  I should have left well enough alone, but I think it's rather too late for that. What do I do to correct all this?

I installed it upon getting an update notice mentioning the availability of an update from ubuntu. I downloaded it from the ubuntu site.

Comment: [edit] your question with further detail for example how was 22.04 installed (update or from scratch) and the softwares you mention. As it currently stands, your question is unanswerable. Perhaps back up all your important stuff and install 20.04LTS?

Comment: I think that might be the best...to install 20.04 again.  That doesn't appear to be that easy, though.  What would you suggest? What is apparently suggested is bit torrent. What do I need to do that?

Comment: you might find [this reference about BitTorrent](https://www.xmodulo.com/download-iso-image-bittorrent-command-line.html) helpful then.

Comment: I have been having some trouble with a usb drive (for back-up purposes) having to do with it getting into read-only, but I have a vague recollection of having dealt with that before.  Also, updates keep coming along.  Maybe I'll continue attempts at resolving the read-only drive problem, and wait and see whether or not the right updates will come along and fix things. (A pious hope???)

Comment: I did not load the previous version again.  Let me try to phrase questions better.  Why do some apps come up as black screens?  Why can't you close those apps that do that? 22.04  keeps getting updates, but doesn't solve the problem.  The apps are the ones I mentioned above.